# Basic Rails - ActiveRecord scope not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to call an ActiveRecord model scope from the controller.  But when I do this, it just returns nil even though the query works perfectly fine.

Here is the model:

```
class Stats < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :by_latest_date, ->{select("date, sum(users) AS users, 
                                     sum(clicks) AS clicks").group("date").limit(1)}
end
```

Scope :by_latest_date is supposed to return the sums of users and clicks for the most recent date of records.  But when I call it from the controller:

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController
    def user_stats
        @stats = Stats.by_latest_date
    end
end
```

@stats is simply set to nil when there are records in the database.  When there are no records in the database, it is set to an empty array.

I don't understand why.  The code worked when I copied/pasted the scope query into the controller, and also worked when I put Stats.by_latest_date directly into my RSPEC test.  Perhaps there is something special about controllers and scope blocks?  But if there is, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `,` before the skinny arrow?, it should break the test though...

Comment: yep, it's there in my program so I added it to the question.  The code here paraphrases rather than exactly replicates my code.

Comment: Have you try using lambda instead of the skinny arrow, or even put it into a class method?

Comment: We only need a block because it doesn't take parameters.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql

Comment: You should probably need to add the other columns(users and clicks) to the group clause, something like `group("date, users, clicks")`

Comment: Firstly - what does running this in psql give you? Then add in the group by and see if its what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get a scope to do something it's not designed to do, it's meant for scoping on the base model not aggregation. It might be easier just to create a method. Get it working in the console first as you have done and then put it into the class.

As an aside - is date a date (as in no time component) - if it's a timestamp then the grouping won't be by actual date but by the timestamp so you may only get the last one anyway.

Grouping will order the data anyway because it has to gather it together - but maybe not in the right order, are you sure you're getting what you want?